# Clone object and store document as embedded in Doctrine MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I'd like to create a situation in which I have two collections, one for *articles* and one for *drafts*. An article is a document with a few properties and an array of embedded documents called *features*. A draft is a document with a few properties and it embeds an article document.

In order to achieve this I've created one base object called BaseArticle from which the Article object and DraftArticle inherit. I've created the following objects and mappings:

#### BaseArticle

This class contains all the getters and setter methods for Article and DraftArticle objects. BaseArticle.mongodb.yml contains:

```
BaseArticle:
    type: document
    inheritanceType: COLLECTION_PER_CLASS
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
        propertyOne:
            type: string
        propertyTwo:
            type: string
        features:
            embedded: true
            type: many
            targetDocument: Feature
```

#### Article

This is an empty PHP class that extends BaseArticle. Article.mongodb.yml contains:

```
Article:
  collection: article
  type: document
```

#### Draft

A basic PHP class with getter and setter methods. Draft.mongodb.yml looks like this:

```
Draft:
    collection: drafts
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
        owner:
            type: string
            length: 255
            index: true
        status:
            type: string
            length: 255
            index: true
        data:
            embedded: true
            type: one
            targetDocument: DraftArticle
```

#### DraftArticle

This is an empty PHP class that extends BaseArticle. DraftArticle.mongodb.yml contains:

```
DraftArticle:
    type: embeddedDocument
```

#### Feature

Feature.mongodb.yml contains:

```
Feature:
    type: embeddedDocument
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
        name:
            type: string
        value:
            type: string
```

I let users edit articles and these edits can than be saved as a draft. The workflow to create a draft is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwbMZ.png

In order to be able to save the Article as an embedded document instead of in the article collection, I need to cast the Article object from Article to DraftArticle. PHP has no way to cast object so I create a new object and do a deep copy using the following code instead.

```
protected function cast($destination, $sourceObject)
{
    $sourceClone = clone $sourceObject;

    if (is_string($destination)) {
        $destination = new $destination();
    }
    $sourceReflection = new \ReflectionObject($sourceClone);
    $destinationReflection = new \ReflectionObject($destination);
    $sourceProperties = $sourceReflection->getProperties();
    foreach ($sourceProperties as $sourceProperty) {
        $sourceProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $name = $sourceProperty->getName();
        $value = $sourceProperty->getValue($sourceClone);
        if ($destinationReflection->hasProperty($name)) {
            $propDest = $destinationReflection->getProperty($name);
            $propDest->setAccessible(true);
            $propDest->setValue($destination, $value);
        }
        else {
            $destination->$name = $value;
        }
    }
    return $destination;
}
```

Now I can create a draft and save the article as an embedded document without changing the original document.

```
$draft = new Draft();

// PHP does not support user type casting. Therefore we use a custom cast function
// which creates a new object of the target type and copies all properties.
$draftArticle = $this->cast('DraftArticle', $article);

// This will unset _id
$draftArticle->clearId();

$draft->setArticle(draftArticle);

$this->entityManager->persist($draft);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

When I change the draftArticle or features in the draftArticle before saving, the changes will be saved as well. **However, when I add new features to the draftArticle, these features will be stored in the original Article document as well.**

Why is this? How can I inform doctrine to completely forget about any link between the DraftArticle and its original source Article? Is there a better way to copy/clone a document and store it as an embedded document in another collection?

Answer (score 1):

Take my advice with a grain of salt because I don't know if I've been having the same problem as you exactly. But I have a scenario where I need to "clone" a document using Doctrine ODM from one collection to another.. and I've received a lot of headaches with funky behavior similar to what you describe. I especially had a hard time cloning hash arrays containing referenced documents, but it looks like I finally got it working (for now, who knows when more bugs will creep up).

In the end I found two things helped get rid of the funky behavior.. The first is using $documentManager->clear(); at certain key spots.

In my project I initialize a $documentManager object and then use it through my controllers by using global $documentManager. And I found that if I don't do a $documentManager->clear(); in certain places I get really weird behavior, well weird in the sense that I can't explain why it's doing it but that may be because I lack understanding.

Here's the code I use the clone my document. No idea if it'll help you..

In my case, the images/files/videos are referenced documents stored in a hash array.. so I do something special to get those to be "cloned". I've been looking at your solution too.. it seems cleaner than mine for sure.. but I'm not knowledgeable enough to use the ReflectionObject and entityManager... tbh I wish I understood what those are for.. right now I strictly make use of the $documentManager. Anyway if you find this helpful at all and don't mind replying with a little insight as to what the differences are between what I'm doing and what you're doing.. using the entityManager vs documentManager and using the ReflectionObject to clone.. well I sure would appreciate it. Cheers :)

```
public function cloneDocument($document) {

    $classVars = self::getObjectVars();

    foreach ($classVars as $key => $value) {

        if(in_array($key, array("images", "files", "videos")))
        {
            switch($key)
            {
                case "images":

                    foreach ($document->images as $image) {
                        $this->images[] = $image;
                    }

                    break;

                case "files":

                    foreach ($document->files as $file) {
                        $this->files[] = $file;
                    }

                    break;

                case "videos":

                    foreach ($document->videos as $video) {
                        $this->videos[] = $video;
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->$key = $document->$key;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this advise. It certainly helped! What `$documentManager->clear()` does is detaching all documents that are managed at that point. I found that I could simply call `$this->entityManager->detach($article);` right after fetching the article and that that trick would make my code work like a charm. (By the way, I think that my entity_manager and your documentManager are the same. documentManager is just a better way of naming it when you use Doctrine ODM)